# Interested in setting up capacity for receiving recurring donations

Tags: recurring-contributions

My organization is looking to set up a monthly giving program -- does CiviCRM have the capacity to process/store recurring donations?

Comment: Hi Sarah - it helps the community if you come back to answers and either critique them or +1 / Accept them

Answer (score 1):

Civi works with a number of payment processors, some of which do recurring payments.

I think the best list of which do what is here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but it depends what payment processor you are using - do you have one set up already?

Comment: I've used iats and authorizenet successfully for recurring payments. It might work with others, but I'm not sure

Comment: We use PayPal Giving Fund

Answer (score 0):

And on top of that, for European organizations that need it there is an extension [CiviSepa](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisepa-sepa-direct-debit-extension) to work with SEPA recurring contributions. But not sure what region you are in :-)

Comment: Do you think CiviSepa should be in that documentation I linked to

Comment: Not sure Pete. It really only matters for certain countries and they know it matters :-) But I will add a sentence or two.

Comment: Yes pls do. I suspect some euro organisations 'checking out' civicrm might rely on this documentation to help make decisions